# Unittest Python

Tags: python, юнит-тесты

Для чего вообще нужны Юнит тесты?
В чем суть ?
Единственное что пришло в голову , что они нужны в случае если проект очень большой.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Если у вас маленький проект, это разве значит, что вам всё-равно, правильно ли он работает? ))

Comment: Считайте, что код без тестов - это код Шредингера: пока его не запустишь - не знаешь, рабочий он или нет. Когда код покрыт тестами (даже если частично, например, только критические части), есть какая-то уверенность в его работоспособности.

Answer (score 5):

В большом проекте больше нужды в тестах, но это не значит, что в маленьком от них нет или мало пользы.

Вообще, причин несколько. Вот какие сразу приходят в голову:

1. регрессионное тестирование
2. свидетельство реализации
3. документирование

### Регрессионное тестирование

Допустим вы реализовали какую-то функцию в своей программе. Чтоб проверить, что она работает нужно, скажем, проверить три сценария. Вы проверили - все в порядке. Но на этом разработка не останавливается. Вы делаете новую функцию и ее реализация требует модификаций в коде, который уже написан и используется первой функцией.

Когда закончили со второй функцией, нужно проверить все три сценария для первой функции, чтоб убедиться, что случайно ничего не сломали. И каждое изменение кода, может повлечь за собой ошибки и требует тестирования. Если это делать вручную, то это либо дорого (так как требует времени) либо это становиться лень делать и падает качество.

Автоматические тесты позволяют решить эту проблему хотя бы частично.

Более того, с хорошо написанными тестами, появляется возможность менять реализацию (делать рефакторинг), например, если нужно сделать оптимизацию производительности и не бояться, что изменения сломают существующий функционал.

### Cвидетельство реализации

Допустим, вы реализовали функцию. Как вы можете доказать, что вы ее реализовали? И в каком объеме реализовали? Какие сценарии поддерживаются, а какие нет?

Когда коллега делает ревью кода, то ответы на эти вопросы не так просты, особенно, если функция нетривиальная. Если же есть тесты, то они это обычно хорошо демонстрируют. Я когда делаю ревью, в первую очередь смотрю на тесты, что они делают и соответствуют ли требованиям. Это очень помагает.

### Документирование

Хорошо написанный тест является исполняемой документацией, т.е. читая его видно требования, которые к тому же не могут устареть так, как это может случится с отдельно написаной документацией, которую забыли обновить при изменении кода. С тестом это проще - при изменении кода, если тест на работает, то или в тесте ошибка или в коде, и его нельзя не обновить и нужно поддерживать в актуальном состоянии.